# Loading images with loop to <img> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code:

```
$("input[type=file]").change(function readURL()
{
   if (this.files)
   {
      var num = this.files.length;    
      for(var i = 0; i < num ; i++)
      {
         var file = this.files[i];
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onload = function(qi)
         {
            return function()
            {
            $("#img"+(i)).attr('src',event.target.result);
            };
         }(i);
         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
   }
});
```

And some HTML

```
<img id="img1" class="img-thumbnail thumnbail">
<img id="img2" class="img-thumbnail thumnbail">
<img id="img3" class="img-thumbnail thumnbail">
<img id="img4" class="img-thumbnail thumnbail">
<img id="img5" class="img-thumbnail thumnbail">
...
```

What I'm trying to do is to load all images as a thumbnails to  tags, but only last is being loaded.
Adding `console.log(i)` to `return` function showed me that this function returns last value of i i times. What I should do to make it work?

Comment: Quick observation: If `qi` starts at zero and your img tags start at `#img1`, you're going to have to add 1 to `$("#img"+(qi+1))` to see the first image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have correctly created a closure, which is the right thing to do, but you are still referencing the `i` variable from the upper scope, not `qi` from the closure.

Change this:

```
$("#img"+(i)).attr('src',event.target.result);
```

To:

```
$("#img"+(qi)).attr('src',event.target.result);
//        ^^ use qi here
```